# node.js Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to login to my own overleaf (sharedlatex) community server via LDAP. Connection to Active Directory works. But after an successfull authentication i get the following error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/var/www/sharelatex/web/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/var/www/sharelatex/web/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/var/www/sharelatex/web/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:249:15)
    at /var/www/sharelatex/web/app/src/Features/Authentication/AuthenticationController.js:133:15
    at tryCatcher (/var/www/sharelatex/web/node_modules/standard-as-callback/built/utils.js:11:23)
    at promise.then (/var/www/sharelatex/web/node_modules/standard-as-callback/built/index.js:19:49)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

This leads to wrong username/password message, also if the credentials are correct.

For the login procedure I'm using the following code:

```
    ldapAuth(query, passwd, onSuccess, callback, adminMail, userObj) {
        const client = ldap.createClient({
            url: process.env.LDAP_SERVER
        });
        const bindDn = process.env.LDAP_BIND_DN
        const bindPassword = process.env.LDAP_BIND_PW
        client.bind(bindDn, bindPassword, function (err) {
            if (err == null) {
                const opts = {
                    filter: '&(sAMAccountName=' + query.email.split('@')[0] + ')',
                    scope: 'sub',
                    attributes: ['dn']
                };

                client.search('ou=Users,ou=xxxxxx,dc=xxxxx,dc=xx', opts, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        return callback(null, null)
                    }
                        res.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
                        userDn = entry.objectName
                        client.bind(userDn, passwd, function (err) {
                            if (err == null) {
                                console.log("ldap positive")
                                onSuccess(query, adminMail, userObj, callback)
                                client.unbind()
                                return null
                            } else {
                                console.log("ldap negative")
                                client.unbind()
                                return callback(null, null)
                            }
                        })
                    })
                    res.on('error', err => {
                        console.error('error: ' + err.message);
                        client.unbind()
                        return callback(null, null)
                   });

                    res.on('end', result => {
                        //if nothing written (user not found)
                        if(result.connection._writableState.writing == false){
                            client.unbind()
                            return callback(null, null)
                        }
                    });
                });

            } else {
                return callback(null, null)
            }
        })
    }
```

After searching a while in the net I found out, that the problem is caused by sending header twice or something like that. If I comment out following lines, the login works as intended. But then, when the user is not found in Active Directory the login hangs up instead of saying wrong username/password.

```
                    res.on('end', result => {
                        //if nothing written (user not found)
                        if(result.connection._writableState.writing == false){
                            client.unbind()
                            return callback(null, null)
                        }
                    });
```

I tried to modify the code many to get it work but without success. I shouldn't be hard to find the mistake for someone who is familar with node.js. But I'm a bloody noob. ^^

Can someone maybe help me?

Thank you!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cant set headers after they are sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349910/cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)

Comment: hm.. not really :(  I know, that the problem is that headers are sent twice, but I don't know how to solve it...